# How to check whether my data is saved on web server api through the console in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application where I am sending my data to my web server API via entering values in `textfields` and getting the response through the server. I have written the following code to send data to the server. I want to receive the data from the server in JSON format.

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface apicontroller : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtfirstName;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtlast;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserName;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
    NSMutableData *webData;
    

}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *txtUserName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *txtPassword;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *txtfirstName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *txtlast;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextField *txtEmail;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableData *webData;

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender;


@end
```

This is my .m file:

```
#import "apicontroller.h"


@implementation apicontroller

-(void)sendRequest
{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key1=%@&key2=%@&key3=%@&key4=%@&key5=%@",txtfirstName.text,txtlast.text,txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text,txtEmail.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Register&Command=NEW"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    
    if (theConnection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);
    }
    else 
    {
     
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{   
    [webData setLength: 0]; 
} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{         
    [webData appendData:data]; 

} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{     
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 

} 


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  
    //greeting.text = loginStatus;   
    [loginStatus release];           
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 
} 

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    NSString *first = txtfirstName.text;
    NSString *last = txtlast.text;
    NSString *user = txtUserName.text;
    NSString *pass = txtPassword.text;
    NSString *email = txtEmail.text;
    [self sendRequest];
    
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [txtfirstName resignFirstResponder];
    [txtlast resignFirstResponder];
    [txtUserName resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [txtEmail resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

When I run this code and enter values in the `textfield` and click on the button I get the following response on the console:

> {"isError":true,"ErrorMessage":"First name is required. Last name is required. Password is required. Email is required. Username is required.","Result":null,"ErrorCode":903}

But I have passed all the parameters to the API.
Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: this is respond you web server. I guess it's not depend from u code

Comment: Hi @Alex , i didn't get u what u want to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at your last question, your server seems to expect all the data in the URL:

```
 http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Register&Command=NEW&firstname=rocky&lastname=singh&Username=rocky14&Password=xxx&Email=rocky@gmail.com
```

But you send part of the request in the URL and part of the request as URL-encoded data in the HTTP body.

Furthmore, you use the very generic names *key1*, *key2*, *key3* etc. instead of the specific ones (*firstname*, *lastname*, *username*, *password* etc.)

Overall, the problem most likely is that you aren't sending the request in the format the server expects. Without a description of the server API, it'll be difficult to really pinpoint the problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks now it is working .My data is getting posted to my api server

Comment: But i have one problem,all this values are saved to my server database and i want that this values should be saved to my local database through JSON.

Comment: What sort of local database? On your iPhone? Why are you sending the data to the server in the first place if you don't want to store it there?

Comment: the problem is i dont know JSON properly.i want to read values that are on server  through JSON and save it in the local database.How is this possible.Thanks

Comment: Sqlite database on iphone.i want to save data  on web server and at the same time save data on the sqlite database

Comment: Please post a separate question regarding SQLite describing what data is sent to the server, what data is received from the server and what data needs to be stored locally. So far your description of the overall data architecture is very confusing.